# Are there ways of preventing flash cookies from being cross-browser accessible?

Tags: linux, browser, privacy, cookies, cross-browser

I hope this is right place to ask. I'd wish that each browser in my computer (running in the same OS) had its own flash cookies ('Local Shared Objects') and were unable access each other's. Could it be done?

My primary OS is Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

If privacy is what you want, use Better Privacy addon for firefox, it will delete the LSO.

Or, you could just make a wrapper for each browser.

```
mv /usr/local/bin/firefox /usr/local/bin/_firefox
vim /usr/local/bin/firefox # write your script
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/firefox
```

Create .lso/firefox,chromium,safari directories and make each wrapper just link the directory that is supposed to hold the LSOs to the directory of the concerned browser.

When firefox is launched it will set the global LSO directory to it's own LSO directory, so each browser will access its own cookies.